# Synonyms Water, Hydration and Dehydration

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup, tag-synonyms

The questions under those tags basically are all the same in my eyes.

[water](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water)
[hydration](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hydration)
[dehydration](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dehydration)

I think we should at least merge the last two, but honestly I think we can include water, too, as there are currently no questions using the *water* tag that are not related to hydration and I can't think of any on topic questions that would need a water tag unrelated to hydration on fitness.SE

Comment: If someone mentions swimming I will slap him with a trout!

Comment: Swimming! Swimming has water. I like swimming.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's fine. [hydration](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hydration) and [dehydration](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dehydration) should definitely be merged, and I can't see any reason to have [water](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water) not be merged as well if it's only being used in reference to either hydration or dehydration. We can address anything else that comes up with them later.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13475/how-do-you-effectively-train-for-running-while-in-the-water) is a question which is quite rightly tagged with [water](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water), and is definitely not [swimming](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swimming) or [hydration](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hydration).  I think we will limit ourselves if we combine all three into one.  There's clearly a difference between water for hydration and water as a physical medium in exercise.

My proposal:

- [hydration](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hydration) refers to human body water levels, inc. any drinking related questions
- [water](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water) refers to water as a physical medium in sport, whether it be an obstacle or playing field.  Note we have more specific tags like [swimming](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swimming).

Comment: See my edit regarding the tags

Comment: @Informaficker Ah great, thanks for that